# Sequelize postresql id not converted to serial type on migrate

Tags: sequelize.js

Is this a bug in sequelize or my config is wrong?

Postgresql version: 11
sequelize version: 5 latest
nodejs version: 12

model

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/db');

module.exports = db.define('status', {
  id: {
    field: 'status_id',
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  status_code: Sequelize.STRING(50),
  status_name: Sequelize.STRING(50)
});
```

Migration

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('status', {
      id: {
        field: 'status_id',
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      status_code: Sequelize.STRING(50),
      status_name: Sequelize.STRING(50)
    });
  },

  down: queryInterface => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('status');
  }
};
```

status_id field becomes int4.

Comment: You declared `status_id` to be: `type: Sequelize.INTEGER` on the migration. What did you expect?

Comment: I thought it will adopt Postgres id type of serial on table creation instead of int.

Comment: @Naor Levi as the documentation stated that autoIncrement: true will automatically convert an integer to serial in id https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/legacy/